# Is this javascript code supposed to be here?

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

When checking my [webshop](https://www.superstylishwebshop.com) in 1.9.0.1 i get a big field of javascript text... is this supposed to be here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
        var Translator = new Translate({"HTML tags are not allowed":"HTML tags zijn niet toegestaan","Please select an option.":"Selecteer een optie.","This is a required field.":"Dit is een verplicht veld.","Please enter a valid number in this field.":"Voer in dit veld een geldig nummer in.","The value is not within the specified range.":"De waarde ligt niet in het toegestane gebied.","Please use numbers only in this field. Please avoid spaces or other characters such as dots or commas.":"Gebruik alleen getallen in dit veld. Vermijd spaties of andere tekens zoals punten of komma's.","Please use letters only (a-z or A-Z) in this field.":"Gebruik a.u.b. alleen letters (a-z of A-Z) in dit veld.","Please use only letters (a-z), numbers (0-9) or underscore(_) in this field, first character should be a letter.":"Gebruikt alleen letters (a-z of A-Z), getallen (0-9) of underscore(_) in dit veld, eerste teken moet een letter zijn.","Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z) or numbers (0-9) only in this field. No spaces or other characters are allowed.":"Gebruik alleen letters (a-z of A-Z) of nummers (0-9) in dit veld. Spaties en andere karakters zijn niet toegestaan.","Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z) or numbers (0-9) or spaces and # only in this field.":"Gebruikt alleen letters (a-z of A-Z), getallen (0-9), spaties of #  in dit veld.","Please enter a valid phone number. For example (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890.":"Voer een geldig telefoonnummer in. Bijvoorbeeld (123) 456-7890 of 123-456-7890.","Please enter a valid fax number. For example (123) 456-7890 or 123-456-7890.":"Voer een geldig faxnummer in. Bijvoorbeeld (123) 456-7890 of 123-456-7890.","Please enter a valid date.":"Voer a.u.b. een geldige datum in.","The From Date value should be less than or equal to the To Date value.":"De waarde van de Begin Datum moet kleiner zijn dan of gelijk aan de waarde van de Eind Datum.","Please enter a valid email address. For example johndoe@domain.com.":"Voer a.u.b. een geldig e-mailadres in. Bijvoorbeeld johndoe@domain.com.","Please use only visible characters and spaces.":"Gebruik alleen zichtbare karakters en spaties.","Please enter 6 or more characters. Leading or trailing spaces will be ignored.":"Voer 6 of meer karakters in a.u.b. Spaties worden genegeerd.","Please enter 7 or more characters. Password should contain both numeric and alphabetic characters.":"Geef 7 of meer karakters in. Wachtwoord moet zowel cijfers als letters bevatten.","Please make sure your passwords match.":"Let er alstublieft op dat de wachtwoorden overeenkomen.","Please enter a valid URL. Protocol is required (http:\/\/, https:\/\/ or ftp:\/\/)":"Voer een geldige URL in. Protocol is vereist (http:\/\/, https:\/\/ of ftp:\/\/)","Please enter a valid URL. For example http:\/\/www.example.com or www.example.com":"Voer a.u.b. een geldige YRL in. Bijvoorbeeld http:\/\/www.voorbeeld.com of www.voorbeeld.com","Please enter a valid URL Key. For example \"example-page\", \"example-page.html\" or \"anotherlevel\/example-page\".":"Voer a.u.b. een geldige URL sleutel in. Bijvoorbeeld \"voorbeeld-pagina\", \"voorbeeld-pagina.html\" of \"eenanderniveau\/voorbeeld-pagina\".","Please enter a valid XML-identifier. For example something_1, block5, id-4.":"Voer a.u.b. een geldige XML-identificeerder in. Bijvoorbeeld iets_1, blok5, id-4.","Please enter a valid social security number. For example 123-45-6789.":"Voer a.u.b. een geldig BSN-nummer in. Bijvoorbeeld 123456789.","Please enter a valid zip code. For example 90602 or 90602-1234.":"Voer a.u.b. een geldige postcode in. Bijvoorbeeld 1234 AB.","Please enter a valid zip code.":"Voer een geldige postcode in.","Please use this date format: dd\/mm\/yyyy. For example 17\/03\/2006 for the 17th of March, 2006.":"Gebruik dit datumformat: dd\/mm\/jjjj. Bijvoorbeeld 17\/03\/2006 voor 17 maart 2006.","Please enter a valid $ amount. For example $100.00.":"Voer a.u.b. een geldig \u20ac hoeveelheid in. Bijvoorbeeld \u20ac100,00.","Please select one of the above options.":"Selecteer alstublieft een van de bovenstaande opties.","Please select one of the options.":"Selecteer alstublieft een van de opties.","Please select State\/Province.":"Selecteer Staat\/Provincie.","Please enter a number greater than 0 in this field.":"Voer a.u.b. een nummer groter dan 0 in dit veld.","Please enter a number 0 or greater in this field.":"Voer een nummer groter dan 0 in.","Please enter a valid credit card number.":"Voer a.u.b. een geldig creditcardnummer in.","Credit card number does not match credit card type.":"creditcardnummer komt niet overeen met creditcardtype","Card type does not match credit card number.":"Kaarttype komt niet overeen met het nummer van de credit card.","Incorrect credit card expiration date.":"Onjuiste creditcard vervaldatum.","Please enter a valid credit card verification number.":"Voer a.u.b. een geldig creditcard verificatienummer in.","Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z), numbers (0-9) or underscore(_) in this field, first character should be a letter.":"Gelieve alleen de letters (a-z of A-Z), nummers (0-9) en\/of laag streepje(_) in dit veld te gebruiken, het eerste karakter moet een letter zijn.","Please input a valid CSS-length. For example 100px or 77pt or 20em or .5ex or 50%.":"Voer een geldige CSS-lengte in. Bijvoorbeeld 100px, 77pt, 20em, .5ex of 50%","Text length does not satisfy specified text range.":"Tekst lengte voldoet niet aan de vereiste tekstgebiedsvoorwaarden.","Please enter a number lower than 100.":"Voer a.u.b. een nummer beneden de 100 in dit veld.","Please select a file":"Selecteer een bestand","Please enter issue number or start date for switch\/solo card type.":"Voer uitgavenummer in of start datum voor switch\/solo kaarttype.","Please wait, loading...":"Even geduld alstublieft, bezig met laden...","This date is a required value.":"Deze datum is een vereiste waarde","Please enter a valid day (1-%d).":"Voer a.u.b. een geldige dag in (1-%d).","Please enter a valid month (1-12).":"Voer een geldige maand in (1-12).","Please enter a valid year (1900-%d).":"Voer een geldig jaar in (1900-%d).","Please enter a valid full date":"Voer a.u.b. een geldige, volledige datum in","Please enter a valid date between %s and %s":"Voer a.u.b. een geldige datum in tussen %s en %s","Please enter a valid date equal to or greater than %s":"Voer een geldige datum in groter dan of gelijk aan %s","Please enter a valid date less than or equal to %s":"Voer a.u.b. een geldige datum in die minder of gelijk aan %s is.","Complete":"Gereed","Add Products":"producten toevoegen","Please choose to register or to checkout as a guest":"Registreer of betaal zonder account","Your order cannot be completed at this time as there is no shipping methods available for it. Please make necessary changes in your shipping address.":"Je bestelling kan nu niet worden afgerond omdat er geen verzendmethoden beschikbaar zijn. Pas je afleveradres aan.","Please specify payment method.":"Kies betaalmethode","Your order cannot be completed at this time as there is no payment methods available for it.":"Je bestelling kan nu niet worden afgerond omdat er geen betaalmethoden beschikbaar zijn."});
```

Comment: It's not javascript code, it's translation data. On which page do you see this exactly? I can't find it on your webshop.

Comment: it is a big chunk of text but someone edited it out of my post...(don't know why, didn't know this was a language perfect forum ;-)) its in the source code of every page

Comment: In that case you should accept the answer given by Reindex 'Em All.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is perfectly fine.

```
var Translator = new Translate({"HTML tags are not allowed":"HTML tags zijn niet toegestaan","Please select an option.":"Sele....
```

It's purpose is to provide the localization for javascript validation class and some other parts in for example the checkout on frontend. It is equivalent to Magento's translate function **__()**.

Comment: so it is needed there and not obsolete