# Removing start to be viewed in product page and spammed email for seo

Tags: magento-1.7, javascript

I need help in an issue,

When I right click on "inspect element" on my home page which is a magento site, I see the codings as below which includes johndoe@doamin.com. But I can not remove it and whenever I use a seo optimization tool, it says "your plain text has emails that are not hidden. it could cause spam". For seo purpose I want to remove it. 
The images are:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yharg.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlMeI.png

Comment: Or you could just ignore that "seo optimization tool" advice lol

Answer (score 1):

This is related to Magento's translation function. I wouldn't worry too much about it. Also read [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49334/is-this-javascript-code-supposed-to-be-here/49340#49340).

The email adress is fake. It is only displayed in a warning message if and when customers enter an invalid email address. Its purpose is to show them an example of what a valid email address would look like. Also it is not your own email address, so why worry about spam?

Like all other people who answered this question recommend: Just leave this as it is...

But if you really, really, really want to change or remove this then look at the following files:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/jstranslator.xml
app/locale/yourlanguage_YOURLANGUAGE/Mage_Core.csv
/js/prototype/validation.js
```

> **Warning:** Like @Sander says, removing or editing this might be very tricky. So only
>   touch those files if you are exactly aware of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

It's the default email address under `system` > `configuration` > `customer` section. The javascript array it's shown in is the translate array which is usef by Magento for translating certain labels.

Removing it might be tricky but you could should set a non-existing email address.

It won't have any negative influence on your seo. Im guessing the tool just reports it as a warning. So it won't affect your page rank

Comment: Hello Thank you for the Answer Sander, How can I set a non existing email adress or change that adress johndoe@domain.com there. The customer section is seen as below:

http://i.imgur.com/Dun2Vkd.png

Comment: @Sani Please see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

having plain text emails is not really a problem anymore.

First: the spam detection is a lot better today.

Second: the only working alternative would be to not show email addresses at all, which is bad if people would want to contact you via email.
The reason is, every possible obfuscation strategy of emails is worthless since years, as the spam providers have found ways to resolve them.